# Probability of winning a prize in a raffle (each person can only win once)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

So I'm trying to figure out the odds of winning a prize in a raffle where each person can buy multiple tickets but you can only win once. 
My problem is the following:

- There are 2600 tickets sold
- There are 42 winning tickets drawn
- There is no limit on how many tickets you can buy
- I buy 10 tickets
- I know that there are only 600 people who have bought tickets (so all the tickets are distributed over the 600 people)

I have looked at booth of these threads: 
[Thread 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1781384/probability-of-winning-a-prize-in-a-raffle-that-each-person-can-only-win-once)
[Thread 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91998/probability-of-winning-a-prize-in-a-raffle?rq=1)
and they helped me understand the problem well but I am still wondering if there is some way to calculate the probability better when you know how many people who have bought tickets. You still don't know how many tickets each person bought, but maybe you can calculate an average or something similar? I'm also thinking since the price of the tickets is 10$ each, it must be more unlikely someone bought 1000 tickets than say 1,5 or 10.

Any input or help is greatly appreciated!

*Edit:
All the prizes need to be distributed and if a person wins all the rest of their tickets become invalid. So they keep drawing until they have drawn 42 tickets which correspond to 42 unique individuals.

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand of your problem, even if I buy all $2600$ tickets, I can get only **one** prize, i.e. although there are $42$ prizes, all needn't get distributed.

So we needn't bother about how many persons have bought how many tickets,
we can easily compute the $Pr$ that **you** win a prize.

You win a prize if all $42$ prizes don't fall in the $2590$ tickets not with you.

P(you win a prize) $= 1$ - P(you don't win a prize)

$= 1 - \dfrac{\binom{2590}{42}}{\binom{2600}{42}} \approx 0.1223$

Comment: Good analysis of all the red herrings. (+1)

Comment: @hypergeometric: Thanks, there has been a lot of obfuscation on earlier occasions ! :)

Comment: Hmm okay but here all the prizes need to get distributed.Let's say that if a person wins, the rest of their tickets become invalid. So let's say person b has bought 500 tickets and wins on the first draw. Then the next draw after this will only be with 2100 tickets. So if they draw one of person b's tickets again they just do a redraw and doesn't count it. They do this until all the prizes are distributed to 42 different people. 

Is there any way to factor this into the calculations?

Comment: You shouldn't go on changing a question after answer(s) have been received, you should post a new question after careful thought. Now the *order* in which people draw also comes into account. Also, if I won 11 prizes, 10 of the winning numbers get cancelled. How are the "replacement" winning numbers chosen ? Is the shopkeeper handing out prizes person by person, also cancelling numbers, redrawing for the next.. To me it seems a very Kafkaesque lottery !

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker so if a few of my words are hard to understand I'm sorry. But I don't understand how this is a weird lottery. They simply draw tickets until 42 unique people have won. If a ticket is drawn that belonged to someone who has already won, they throw that ticket away and draw a new ticket. This was supposed to be my original question and therefore I didn't think I needed to make a whole new post. When you made the conclusion that not all prizes needn't get distributed (something I didn't specify either) I realized I hadn't specified that and chose to edit it.

Comment: "Lottery" is a generic term, "raffle" and "lotto" are more specific. If you can provide a link that describes a "raffle" of the type you envisage, I can have a re-look, though a priori it would appear that more data will be needed, and no simple generalization will emerge.